# Получить дочерний элемент UI в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как у *canvas* в *unity* через скрипт получить его дочерний `button`, чтобы потом иметь возможность обращаться к нему и проверять на нажатия ?
Пробовал так:

```
GUIElement Button;
 GUIElement[] ge= gameObject.GetComponents<GUIElement>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ge.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ge[i].tag == "button1")
        {
            Button = ge[i];
        }

    }
```

но понятно, что такой вариант не подходит по здравому смыслу. 
Да, я знаю, что в самом редакторе есть встроенный "редактор событий" - по типу `OnClick` - и можно прописать цепочку условий, но там нельзя подписать на свой обработчик событий, поэтому и спрашиваю как обратиться к самой кнопке как к дочернему элементу.

Comment: `такой вариант не подходит по здравому смыслу.` - почему? Если не известно точное положение кнопки - вполне... если известно - то другой вопрос

Comment: ну как то не логично перебирать все элементы canvas-a для получения одной кнопки, да еще и по тегу, да еще и типа GUIElement  - который потом к Button привести не удастся (я проверял  )

Comment: И что? иногда transform в child  так ищут и ничО, не обламываются........как иерархия выглядит? кнопка одна? Она известна на какой позиции будет или скакать?

Comment: Да, кнопка одна. Canvas содержит только эту  копку и еще один елемент - text. Позиция заранее известна.

Comment: @BadCats, а можете пояснить, почему именно поиск? Чем обоснованно нежелание сделать линк через указание [SerializeField]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется нужно всего лишь вот это: **[GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html)**

```
private Button button;

void Start( ) {
    button = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();

    if(button)
         Debug.Log(test.interactable);
    else
        Debug.Log(":'-(");
}
```

Еще варианты, когда известна иерархия объекта. Например использовать **[GetChild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)**

Например есть структура

```
Canvas
  GameObject 
    GameObject
      Button
      Slider
      Image
```

Скрипт например будет висеть на `Canvas` → `GameObject`. Тогда:

```
void Start () {     
    var button = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Button>();     
    Debug.Log(button.interactable);
}
```

Также если известна структура можно использовать **[Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)**:

```
void Start () {
    var button = GameObject.Find("GameObject/Button").GetComponent<Button>();           
    Debug.Log(button.interactable);        
}
```